# Добавление класса только к нужному li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать, чтобы класс добавлялся только к `li` с выбранным чекбоксом.

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu b-dropdown__menu--second-menu js-no-close">
  <li class="js-li-filter">
    <div class="b-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="model-name" id="model-name1">
      <label for="model-name1" class="b-checkbox__name b-checkbox__name--filter">Ringe</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="js-li-filter">
    <div class="b-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="model-name" id="model-name2">
      <label for="model-name2" class="b-checkbox__name b-checkbox__name--filter">Ohrringe</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="js-li-filter">
    <div class="b-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="model-name" id="model-name3">
      <label for="model-name3" class="b-checkbox__name b-checkbox__name--filter">Anhänger</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="js-li-filter">
    <div class="b-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="model-name" id="model-name4">
      <label for="model-name4" class="b-checkbox__name b-checkbox__name--filter">Ketten</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var selected = [];

function onChange(e){
  var checked = $(e.target).prop('checked');
  var li = $('.b-checkbox__name--filter').closest('.js-li-filter');
  if(checked) {
    li.addClass('line-filter');
  } else {
    li.removeClass('line-filter');
  }
}

$('input[name=model-name]').on('change', onChange);
```

Comment: стоит выбирать нужный элемент относительно того по которому кликнули, а не брать все сразу вот тут `$('.b-checkbox__name--filter')`

Comment: добавить класс к чек-боксу?

Comment: нет, добавлять тому элементу которому надо, для этого closest надо вызывать у **одного** чекбокса, а не сразу у всех

Comment: `var li = $('input:checked + .b-checkbox__name--filter').closest('.js-li-filter');` вот как-то так примерно

Comment: var li = $("input:checkbox:checked").closest('.js-li-filter');   вот так тоже работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как используется jQuery, внутри обработчика `this` будет ссылаться на элемент, на который навешано событие.

Таким образом, код обработчика может принять такой вид

```
function onChange(e){
  $(this)
    .closest('.js-li-filter')
    .toggleClass('line-filter',$(this).prop('checked'));  
}
```